# Automated SQL caching

Tags: python, sql, database, memcached

I'm considering my strategy for adding caching to backend. I can cache any particular type of query such as in memcached example for caching a USER lookup:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = ?"
key = 'SQL:' . user_id . ':' . md5sum(sql)
```

But this would involve adding code in various places throughout my application. I see there are some commercial solutions for "automated" caching. But is there any library or basic support for analyzing the various SQL statements being executed and figuring out how to cache them? It may not be as good as a hand tuned approach but before I go down that route is there any option you recommend for providing a more automated caching strategy based on looking at the form/frequency/performance of whatever queries my backend is executing as it runs?

My backend is Python/AWS Chalice Lambda. All the SQL queries go through my own wrapper class. Even if not doing something "intelligent" would you recommend putting all the caching logic at the raw query level or spreading out nearer to the application logic?

Answer (score 1):

In most of cases, you just can trust common cache backends like [memcached](https://memcached.org/). They are implementing LRU strategy. So if you try to put everything into the cache, it automatically keeps up the recent queries in the storage. No profiling but similar result.

One way to do it:

```
import ring
import pymemcache.client

# you must install and run memcached before do this
client = pymemcache.client.Client(('127.0.0.1', 11211))

@ring.memcache(client, expire=3600)  # maximum 3600 seconds
def run_sql(sql):
    result = ... # run your code here
    return result

run_sql("select * form A")  # run at first time
run_sql("select * form A")  # bring cache at second time (for 3600 seconds)
```

You don't need to generate any hash key.

When you want to manually delete the cache:

```
run_sql.delete("select * from A")
```

See docs for details: https://ring-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Note: Not the answer to your question, but if you don't use any ORM, consider to try any sql builder instead of manual writing.

Comment: Perhaps the following question is naive, but this sounds good in many cases but a common case I'd have is where user would change data and then expect to see the changes right away instead of 3600 seconds later. If I could have it so that DB updates would automatically invalidate any cache entries that would now have old data then I wouldn't need to write extra logic to do this. (Ideally there would still be some control over this behavior based on business logic but in general it would somehow figure out which entries to invalidate.) Is something like this possible?

Comment: Though it is not a python stuff, in MySQL, there is query cache: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache.html 
Will you check the doc whether it meets your requirements? Other RDBMS-es have similar solutions too.